# ¿Como seleccionar y obtener el valor de una celda en WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatable, datagrid

[Soy bastante nuevo en WPF]

Quisiera saber como puedo obtener el valor de una celda o varias en WPf, actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto y necesito poder seleccionar una celda o varias celdas y obtener su valor.
Una vez conseguido esto quisiera dar a un boton y recibir ese valor de la celdas para poderlo tratarlo dentro del evento del boton.
¿Que metodo he de crearme en el cs y con que propiedad asigno ese vento a ese datagrid para que cuando pulse el boton pueda obtener el valor de las celdas?

Gracias de ante mano.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas ningun evento en tu datagrid.

El datagrid tiene una propiedad SelectedItems o SelectedCells, que te devuelve los items que estan seleccionados en tu grilla (o las celdas).

Con selectionMode y SelectionUnit, en tu grilla, definis el modo de seleccion que queres que se aplique cuando el usuario se para sobre una celda.

Aca depende el modo de seleccion que uses para tu grilla, el modo de recorrer la seleccion.

Si SelectionUnit esta en FullRow, vas a tener que recorrerla asi:

```
foreach (var i in grilla.SelectedItems)
```

Si SelectionUnit esta en cualquiera de los otros dos modos, vas a tener que recorrerla asi:

```
foreach (var i in grilla.SelectedCells)
```

Todo esto, lo podes hacer en el evento click del propio boton.

Comment: Hola, entiendo lo que me quieres decir, he modificado como veras arriba el DataGrid  y entiendo que no necesita ningn tipo de propiedad mas y que cuado en el ejemplo de codigo te refieres a grilla en realidad es el DataGrid, mi problema ahora es, ¿Como asigno mi DataGrid del Xmal a un nuevo DataGrid del cs? Me explico tu "grilla" necesita unos valores un referencia de un DataGrid del Xmal ¿como se asigna este DataGrid?

Comment: grilla es tu datagrid. no necesitas ninguna asignacion extra

Comment: Lo que quiero decir es que en mi cs no tengo ningun tipo DataGrid, imagino que he de crearme uno vacio y luego pasarle el DataGrid de la Xaml para poder trabajar con esos datos a tiempo real, y asi poder hacer el SelectedCells. como hago esto es mi pregunta

Comment: No.Estas confundido en algo. Todo lo que tienes en el XAML pertenece a tu cs. solo ponle un nombre y ya lo podras acceder desde el CS. es un control atado al codigo del cs.

Comment: Es mas.. mirando tu codigo uno de los datagrid se llama dg. Fijate que puedes acceder a todas sus propiedades y metodos directamente en tu cs...

Comment: Entiendo lo que quieres decir solo asignandole el nombre ya se deberia de vincular, perdona mi inexperiencia. Aun asi en mi cs yo pongo dg.SelectedCells y no me funciona me da error me dice que dg no existe con lo cual no se me esta vinculando, por que puede ser este motivo? y Gracias por todo.

Comment: lo que llamas cs.. es xalm.cs? es el codigo de atras del xalm? o es una clase cualquiera? si es el codigo de atras, ese error no te puede estar dando. O estas en un modelo mvvm? y estas en el vm?

Comment: Estoy en un modelo mvvm, asi trabaja mi empresa y es como me ha tocado trabajar a mi. La clase Cs me refiero en concreto a la de codigo

Comment: entonces donde estas parado? en el vm? es mas complejo si estas en el vm. Tu code behind deberia avisarle a tu vm cuales son los items ingresados de alguna forma.

Comment: Te edito la pregunta y te adjunto el codigo completo para que puedas ver mi problema mas facilmente y parado estoy simplemente que necesito obtener el dato de las celdas que se quedan selecionadas para luego poder buscar en mi base de datos esos datos  y poder cambiar estados etc.

Comment: Tu pregunta no tiene nada que ver con lo que planteaste aca. Necesitas leer sobre como funciona mvvm. es mucho mas complejo de lo que pensas.

Comment: Entonces en mvvm se hace de manera diferente, tendre que infromarme. Gracias

Comment: Es que si.. mvvm tiene un modelo en la vm, que esta desconectado del lo que pase en la view.. desde la view tenes que pasarle la info necesaria al vm para que pueda actuar. Tenes que crear un metodo en la vm que reciba los items seleccionados, eso lo tenes que hacer en el codebehind de la view. No pasarle un control (la teoria dice que la vm es agnostica de eso). deberias pasarle una lista o coleccion o lo que sea de las cosas seleccionadas. aca ya no hay una sola forma de hacerlo, y cada uno tiene su librito sobre como se hace. Lee sobre mvvm. Y cuando tengas  mas claro que necesitas, avisa